# why i am getting DefenderApiResponseError: Request failed with status code 413 in some contracts

Tags: safe-core, defender

So, the problem is when i call defender.proposeUpgradeWithApproval it runs in some contracts but gives the below error is some, I have a script which do upgrades for all 10 contracts but it fails in some of them.
DefenderApiResponseError: Request failed with status code 413

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem comes from OpenZeppelin Defender rather than Safe{Core} SDK. I suggest you look for solutions in that direction.

Hope it helps, Louis